# Search Vertically and Horizontally in 2D Array

Tags: c++

Basically I want to do a search Horizontally, and also Vertically. Right now I am doing this:

```
void checkHorizontal()
for (int iii = 1; iii<Row;; iii++)
{
    for (int jjj = 1; jjj<Col; jjj++)      //for every col
    {
        if(Array[iii][jjj]==sign)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }

    }
}

void checkVertical()
for (int iii = 1; iii<Col;; iii++)
{
    for (int jjj = 1; jjj<Row; jjj++)      //for every row
    {
        if(Array[jjj][iii]==sign)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }

    }
}
```

Yet, except the check function inside the for loop and the if statement, everything else is the same. And I want to reduce duplicate code, so what can I do to make a more generic function and caller just need to pass in saying if they want to do a Horizontal search or Vertical search (i.e. `void check(string mode)` and caller just `check("Vertical")`)

I know I can get pass the check function inside the for loop by doing something like this:

```
if (mode == "Horizontal")
{
    firstBoundary = cGameBoard.m_nRow;
    secondBoundary = cGameBoard.m_nCol;
}
else if (mode == "Vertical")
{
    firstBoundary = cGameBoard.m_nCol;
    secondBoundary = cGameBoard.m_nRow;
}
void check(string mode)
for (int iii = 1; iii<firstBoundary;; iii++)
{
    for (int jjj = 1; jjj<secondBoundary; jjj++)     
    {
        if(Array[jjj][iii]==sign)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }

    }
}
```

the problem is the if statement, don't know the best way of swapping the array except doing a function call to do it.
My proposal:

```
bool if(string mode, int& iii, int &jjj, array,string sign)
{
    if(mode=="Horizontal")
        return array[iii][jjj]==sign;
    else if(mode=="Vertical")
        return array[jjj][iii]==sign;
}
```

And call this function inside if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work.

```
void check(bool dir){  // Using a bool will have better performance for checking the mode than string comparisons. Especially since you only have two directions
  size_t iEnd = (dir)? cols : rows;
  size_t jEnd = (dir)? rows : cols;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < iEnd; ++i){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < jEnd; ++j){
      if(cond(i, j, dir)){
        // Do something
      } else {
        // Do something else
      }
    }
  }
}

bool cond(const size_t& i, const size_t& j, bool dir){
  if (dir){
    return array[i][j] == sign;
  } else {
    return array[j][i] == sign;
  }
}
```

You could achieve the same results by using recursion

```
void check(size_t i, size_t j, bool dir){
  if (ROW + COL - (i+j) == 1) return;  /* end recursion */
  if (i == ROW) return check(0, j+1, dir);
  if (j == COL) return check(i+1, 0, dir);
  if (array[i][j] == sign){
     // Do Something
  } else {
     // Do Something Else
  }
  if (dir)
    return check(i+1, j, dir);
  return check(i, j+1, dir);
}
```

You're compiler should be able to figure out this only uses tail recursion and you don't have to worry about stack frame limit.